# Adobe flash player and DirectShow filters in IE

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, directshow

I have a question for flash guru.

For video capture of webcams for sites with flash (youtube, livestream and etc) I use a driver and DirectShow filter.  The user loads a page with flash and chooses a driver or filter from the camera list of flash's Parameters for video capture.

My problem. For Win 8.1 x64 in Internet Explorer 11 the flash does not show DirectShow filters,  only drivers. Why?  I see those filters in Chrome, Firefox and Skype, but it is not in IE! No problem with IE in flash for Win 7 x86/x64.

Please any ideas.

PS. OS, browsers, flash player have the last updates on PC.

Comment: The question was solved.

Comment: how exactly were you able to solve this problem? We are facing the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There were two problems:

1). 64-bit browser/flash and 32-bit directshow filter. 32 filter will not work with 64-bit browser. I rewrote the filter to 64 bit and the 64-bit Chrome/VLC saw it. 
2). IE/Flash 64 bit in Win 8,1. IE is a part of OS, so MS added the additional security features there, so IE will work only with drivers.